# Skip line in ListBox C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've want to populate a ListBox with a roulette game but I need to skip lines which doesn't work

If the winning numbers doesn't match the list box must print as follow

Sorry there was no winning number!

You Loose!!!

And if the winning number DOES match the betting number it should look like this:

Winning Number #

Bet: R#

Bet-Type: #

Total Winnings: R#

note: # represents the numbers choosen

I've tried two ways the "/n" and "system.Enviroment.NewLine" and nothing seems to work

```
protected void btnSpin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    intNumbRolled = random.Next(36);

    if (intNumb == intNumbRolled)
    {
        winning = intBet * type;
    }
    else
    {
        winning = 0;
    }

    if (winning == 0)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add
            ("Sorry there was no winning number \nYou loose!!");
    }
    else
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add ("Winning number is " + intNumbRolled + 
            System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine + "BET: R " +
            intBet + System.Environment.NewLine + "Bet-Type: " + type +
            System.Environment.NewLine + "Total Winnings: R " + winning);
    }
}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: What is `intNumb`? Where do you initialize that number?

Comment: Why do you even use a listbox for this? Using just a `Label` would be much simpler and more user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Listbox items can't display multi-line text. You should probably use a different control. `Label` comes to mind, or `TextBox` with `TextMode="multiline"`.

Comment: Yes. And you can set it's `ReadOnly` property to `true` so that the user can't change the content.

Comment: okay lets say i want to use a textbox, changed it to multiline and read only how do I populate it? I know for a list box its listbox.items.add whats it for a textbox

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `repeater control` with `template column` you can add to this template column `TextArea` control

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" 
     DataSource="<% databindingexpression %>"
     runat=server>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <textarea rows="3" cols="30" id="IdTextArea" runat="server"/>  
   </ItemTemplate>
<asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `Repeater` be way too much for something as simple as this? I think a Label or TextBox would be enough for this.

Comment: Eroc Gtx2 i added repeater because if Night programmer uses ListBox => he needs use control with collection orientation, so i suggested repeater, who offers this aspect, and with flexibility about build template

Comment: It looks like he just wants to print out some simple text.

Comment: yes textBox print just text, but you don't have solution to iterate about collection, for this need i suggest Repeater

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can display blank lines in a `ListBox` but if your other text is too long, users would have to scroll sideways which is usually a pain. I'd suggest you use a `Label` instead.

In your .aspx page:

```
...
<asp:Label id="lblResult" runat="server" />
...
```

In your .aspx.cs code-behind:

```
if (winning==0)
{
    lblResult.Text = "Sorry there was no winning number<br />You loose!!";
}
else
{
    lblResult.Text =
        "Winning number is " + intNumbRolled + "<br /><br />" +
        "BET: R " + intBet + "<br />" +
        "Bet-Type: " + type + "<br />" +
        "Total Winnings: R " + winning;
}
```

Notice the use of `<br />` instead of `\n`, since your output is HTML. Using this approach you can also use CSS to format your output.